# Missing complex.h for compiling C with complex analysis

Tags: c, xcode, macos

How do I compile and run C code with a complex analysis on macOS High Sierra. There is no <complex.h> available in Xcode. Is there a download available that would provide this ability?

Answer (score 1):

**complex.h** is present in `/usr/include` directory after you have installed Xcode and Command Line Tools. There is no need to download it separately.

Since you already have Xcode installed, you need to check if you have Command Line Tools installed. To check if it's installed, run `xcode-select -p`. The return value will be 2 if it's **not** installed, and 0 if they are.